# Pandas plot: How to add ```hue``` parameter to pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the below graph obtained the following code:

```
x_var, y_var = 'category', 'instance'
df.groupby(x_var)[y_var].nunique().plot.bar(stacked=False)
```

I want to add `hue` element using `Corr` column, on top of this so that I can see the distribution of the `Corr` across each category.

`hue` is not being accepted as valid parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No direct answer but a workaround.

- Add the column that needs to be the `hue` in the group function.
- pivot the dataframe on that column. (in `columns`. And use the aggregated column above in `values`)

````
price_auckey = plot_test_compress_prd.groupby([x_var,'Corr'],as_index=False)[y_var].nunique()\ # groups no. of unique auctions by Price bucket & Correlation 
                                     .pivot(index=x_var, columns=['Corr'], values=y_var)\ # flattening on the column to be the ``hue```
                                     .plot.bar(stacked=False)
````

[image]